# Has there been any explanation of why Kagame avoided the 'family photo' at the US-Africa Leaders Summit?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, rwanda

The US-Africa Leaders Summit was held in Washington from December 13th to the 15th, and according to the White House, was intended to "demonstrate the United States’ enduring commitment to Africa, and will underscore the importance of U.S.-Africa relations and increased cooperation on shared global priorities".

However, upon reviewing the ['family photo'](https://www.flickr.com/photos/195340062@N05/52565931121/in/album-72177720304468471/) taken at the end of the summit, I notice that one of the more high-profile leaders is missing - President Paul Kagame of Rwanda. Has anything been published from either the US or the Rwandan side explaining why Kagame did not take part? It could be that this is as innocent as a diary clash, but I wonder if there's more to it, given, for example, Kagame's [recent comments on Paul Rusesabagina](https://archive.vn/Rw4wP), who the US has determined as "wrongfully detained" in Rwanda.

[image]